# creating header css - browser compatability issues with IE and Chrome.

Tags: html, css

I want to use this pic as header to my website but iam facing problem with compatibly with browser its not look like I want in IE while its look okay in chrome for sure I split the picture in to part I got one and herf as image and the second  `div` I give it as background color

here is how its look like in chrome
http://www.4shared.com/photo/IifrVQyF/chrome.html?
here is how its look like in IE 
http://www.4shared.com/photo/dDi_KlKS/IE_online.html?
and here is how i am doing it

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<style type="text/css">
@import"style.css.css";
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <div id="HeaderLeftDiv"></div>
  <div id="HeaderRightDiv">
        <ul>
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="RegistrationForm.php">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

here is the css file

```
HeaderLeftDiv
{
    border:"1";
    position:absolute;
    top:12px;
    left:19%;
    width:22%;
    height:13%;
    background:url(Images/Img1.png);
}

HeaderRightDiv
{
    position:relative;
    top:36px;
    left:40%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 54px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    border:3px;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you conidered the fact that by default IE has a margin on the body?

```
body{margin:0}
```

Should fix your problem.